# How to find if an extreme point is degenerate algebraically?

Tags: linear-programming

Is there a method to algebraically determine if an extreme point is degenerate?  Can someone please explain to me.

Here's my example:
$$\max x + 2y $$

subject to,
\begin{align}
x - 4y &\leqslant 4 \\
-2x +y &\leqslant 2 \\
-3x +4y &\leqslant 12 \\
2x + y &\leqslant 8 \\
x, y &\geqslant 0 
\end{align}
And you find your extreme points $(0,0), (4,0), (20/11, 48/11), (4/5, 18/5)$ and $(0,2)$.
I know the optimal point is $(20/11, 48/11)$, but how can I determine if any of these points are degenerate without the graphs? thank you.

Comment: Suggest you use latex / mathjax to format the question more legibly.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) page for advice on formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitue those points in the inequalities and see how many are active. If exactly one pair of them is active, then it is not degenerate. For example $(0,0)$ only make $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ active. It is not degenerate.

Otherwise, if you can find more than two constraints. Verify if you can find two sets of two-constraints that are linearly independent.
For example $(4,0)$ makes $x-4y \le 4$, $2x+y \le 8$ and $y \ge 0$ active. We can verify that $x-4y=4, 2x+y=8$ gives the solution uniquely. Also $x-4y=4$ and $y=0$ uniquely as well. It is degenerate.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer.  By active do you mean like binding?  I can see that now, and since this is two dimensional is that why its pairs of constraints?  So if it was 3d it would three at a time, etc.?  Also, what do you mean by the independence check, may you please tell?  thank you so much!!

Comment: yes, binding. For example, we check $x-4y=4, 2x+y=8$ gives a unique solution. Also $x-4y=4, y=0$ gives a  unique solution. Hence it is degenerate.

Comment: Got it, thank you!